# How to update rhandsontable output following manual row move?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I am trying to create an rhandsontable output that recalculates everytime a row is manually dragged and moved.

Through some searching on the internet, I have been able to produce a script where the output recalculates on the first manual row move, but cannot get it to update on subsequent row moves. I don't know how correct the existing method is, particularly the JS code section, but it seemed like a step in the right direction.

A simplified version of the current script is below. In this example, I would want the bottom row 'Value' to recalculate to 1 each time a row is dragged and moved. Currently, it only calculates the first time a row is dragged and moved.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(rhandsontable)
    library(htmlwidgets)

underlying_table_data <- data.frame("Names" = c("A", "B", "C"), "Value" = c(0,0,0))

jsCode <- c(
    "function(el, x) {",
    "  Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRowMove', function(movedRows, finalIndex, dropIndex, movePossible, orderChanged){",
    "    Shiny.setInputValue('newRow', {movedRows: movedRows, finalIndex:finalIndex, dropIndex:dropIndex, movePossible: movePossible, orderChanged:orderChanged});",
    "  });",
    "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
               rHandsontableOutput("table"), 
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues(data = underlying_table_data)

    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(values$data, manualRowMove = T, readOnly = T) %>%
            onRender(jsCode)
    })

    observeEvent(
        input$newRow$movedRows,
           {if(!is.null(input$newRow$movedRows)){
                values$data[3, 'Value'] = 1
        }
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the case that it only calculates the first time a row is dragged and moved - it calculates every time after a row is moved, but `values$data[3, 'Value'] = 1` just says: Set the value of the `Value` column in the third row of the *data* to 1. What you need to do is to change the value in the *rhandsontable* object.

Therefore, you can change the `JS` to the following one and remove the `observeEvent` which is invoked after `Shiny.setInputValue` is called.

```
function(el, x) {
    Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRowMove', function() {
        this.setDataAtCell(this.countRows() - 1, 1, 1);
    });
}
```

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(htmlwidgets)

underlying_table_data <- data.frame("Names" = c("A", "B", "C"), "Value" = c(0,0,0))

jsCode <- c(
    "function(el, x) {",
    "  Handsontable.hooks.add('afterRowMove', function(){",
    "    this.setDataAtCell(this.countRows() - 1, 1, 1);",
    "  });",
    "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    rHandsontableOutput("table"), 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    values <- reactiveValues(data = underlying_table_data)
    
    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(values$data, manualRowMove = TRUE, readOnly = TRUE) |> 
            onRender(jsCode)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```